# How to print a 2d array with a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, printing, 2d

I'm trying to print a 2d array with a function, but I keep getting the error `"pointer expected"`

I'm trying to make a battleship-type grid. I'm fine with printing out the co-ordinate row and column, but I can't actually get the 2d array (which contains "." in every element) to print at all.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm very new to this. Thanks! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int length;
int width;
int i;
int j;
char invisible_board;


void board_setup(int *rows, int *columns){
    char *invisible_board[*rows][*columns];
char *player_board[*rows][*columns];

for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < *columns; j++){
        invisible_board[i][j] = ".";    //Sets all elements in hidden board to water
    }       
}

for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < *columns; j++){
        player_board[i][j] = ".";
    }
}
}

void display(int *rows, int *columns, char *invisible_board){

printf("   ");
for (i=1; i < *rows +1;i++){
    printf("%d  ",i);
}
printf("\n");                       //Prints top row of co-ordinates

for (i=1; i < *columns+1;i++){
    printf("%d ",i);
    for (j=0;j < *columns;j++){         //Prints left column of co-    ordinates and rows of game board
            printf(" %c ",invisible_board[i-1][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        }

}

int main(void){

    printf("Please enter the amount of rows in your board\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    printf("Please enter the amount of columns in your board\n");
    scanf("%d",&width);

    board_setup(&length,&width);
    display(&length,&width,&invisible_board);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your program has a lot of problems, including that you're shadowing the global `invisible_board` with a local variable in `board_setup`.  I think you have some fundamental understanding problems here.  Certainly just printing is not the only thing going wrong.  A good place to start will be with better formatting.  After that, try loading your code in a debugger and stepping through it. That will help you see some problems.  In particular, you should probably read [the "arrays and pointers" section of the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: In the meantime, I'm going to vote to close as 'not a real question', since I don't think this question is answerable in it's current form.  There are simply too many things going wrong, from style and formatting to fundamental problems with the language.  I don't know that stack overflow is a good place to get a complete refactor & overhaul of a program even this large.  You might benefit from testing smaller chunks of your program and asking questions about them here before moving on to something this complicated.

Comment: @CarlNorum it wasn't too bad, other than not really having space to store the board and using string literals rather than character literals....sure, its not good code, but wasn't that hard to get it to be working code.

Comment: Your example takes out the dynamic allocation, though.  And he also is passing a bunch of parameters by reference unnecessarily.  `rows` and `columns` are swapped in a few places, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum   I didn't take out any dynamic allocation,  I just put it as a comment so it can be done as a future extension,  and yes, its bad code, but it doesn't really matter, first step for people at this stage is to get their code to a working state, then they can play with it :)  its obviously not production code! I hope....please...please please let it not be production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the simplest changes I could make to your code to get you to working code.... now.... this isn't good code yet.   But gets you started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int length;
int width;
int i;
int j;
char invisible_board[100][100];   // dynamically allocate....
char player_board[100][100];   // dynamically allocate....


void board_setup(int *rows, int *columns){  
    for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < *columns; j++){
            invisible_board[i][j] = '.';    //Sets all elements in hidden board to water
        }       
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < *columns; j++){
            player_board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}

void display(int *rows, int *columns){

    printf("   ");
    for (i=1; i < *rows +1;i++){
        printf("%d  ",i);
    }
    printf("\n");                       //Prints top row of co-ordinates

    for (i=1; i < *columns+1;i++){
        printf("%d ",i);
        for (j=0;j < *columns;j++){         //Prints left column of co-    ordinates and rows of game board
            printf(" %c ",invisible_board[i-1][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

int main(void){

    printf("Please enter the amount of rows in your board\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    printf("Please enter the amount of columns in your board\n");
    scanf("%d",&width);

    board_setup(&length,&width);
    display(&length,&width);

    return (0);
}
```